# Access PostgreSQL from Azure Synapse Notebook

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-synapse

PostgreSQL setup in Azure, and I want to create tables, load/read data from Postgres DB using Synapse notebook(Pyspark). How can I do it?

Tried doing using connection string, other is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JDBC driver to connect with Azure PostgreSQL database in Synapse PySpark Notebook.

Change the database configuration as per your database.

```
df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://<servername>:5432/<databasename>") \
    .option("dbtable", <"tablename">) \
    .option("user", <"username">) \
    .option("password", <"password">) \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
    .load()

df.printSchema()
```